# Query to extract data based on one column value

Tags: mysql, sql, join, plsql, case

There are 2 tables that are supposed to have unique product codes but I came across a case where the product code ended up the same for two of the records in another table. I would like to get the product information based on the latest product year. Let's assume I have the following tables.

Table 1:

| recall | id | product_year | product_code |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| yes | 200 | 2019 | 3222333 |
| no | 201 | 2020 | 3222333 |
| yes | 202 | 2021 | 4332233 |
| no | 203 | 2021 | 5446553 |
| yes | 204 | 2018 | 6556677 |

Table 2:

| recall | id | product_year | product_code |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| no | 100 | 2019 | 2245643 |
| yes | 101 | 2020 | 1234543 |
| no | 102 | 2017 | 4332233 |
| yes | 103 | 2022 | 5446553 |
| yes | 104 | 2018 | 3344566 |

Table 3 contains only unique product code information and other updated information based on the latest product year. For eg: product code 3222333 has only one entry even though Table 1 has 2 entries for 3222333. But the problem comes for codes 4332233 and 5446553 which are present in both Table 1 and Table 2.

Table 3:

| country | id | product_code |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Brazil | 301 | 3222333 |
| Indonesia | 302 | 4332233 |
| Argentina | 303 | 6556677 |
| Chile | 304 | 2245643 |
| Brazil | 305 | 1234543 |
| Chile | 306 | 5446553 |
| USA | 307 | 3344566 |

It is known that Table 3 doesn't contain correct data. But I would like to generate a query in mysql to get all the product codes from Table 3 and get the product code related information based on the latest product year. Earlier I was using something like COALESCE(table1.recall, table2.recall, null) assuming that only one value will be present and it works. But for the codes 4332233 and 5446553, it will always pick table 1 column value as recall values for the same product codes are present in both tables 1 and 2. How should I deal with this problem so that I get the data only based on the latest product year?

**Expected output:**

| country | product_code | recall |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Brazil | 3222333 | no |
| Indonesia | 4332233 | yes |
| Argentina | 6556677 | yes |
| Chile | 2245643 | no |
| Brazil | 1234543 | yes |
| Chile | 5446553 | yes |
| USA | 3344566 | yes |

Comment: No may I know why are you asking?

Comment: Is it possible for the same product_code to have the same product_year in both table1 and table2 ?

Comment: @blabla_bingo That's an excellent question. Yes it's possible. In that case may be I need to look at the last updated timestamp I believe.

Comment: Well, if the timestamp data type is used, the timestamp column will be automatically updated to the sysdate when an update is performed for the updated rows, which makes the  referential time unreliable I suppose. Personally I would use a product_date instead of product_year and use `year()` function to extract the year if needs be.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fetch the rows which have the Max value for a column for each distinct value of another column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/121387/fetch-the-rows-which-have-the-max-value-for-a-column-for-each-distinct-value-of)

Answer (score 0):

It did take me some time to realise how convenient it is to use `UNION` in this case. Below is the code written and tested in workbench.Please note this is currently the best answer I can come up with based on the limited table structure and sample data you provided. Since you say that it's possible for the same product_code to have the same product_year in both table1 and table2 and you have other means to determine the latest one, please tweak the code as you see fit. Hope this helps solve your issue.

```
select country, recall,ta.product_code as product_code 
from
    (select product_code,product_year,recall 
    from table1 t1
    union
    select product_code,product_year,recall  
    from table2 t2
    ) ta
join
    (select product_code p_c,max(product_year) mx_y 
    from
        (select product_code,product_year 
        from table1 t1
        union
        select product_code,product_year 
        from table2 t2
        ) t_union
    group by product_code
    ) tb
on ta.product_code=p_c and ta.product_year=mx_y
join table3 t3
on p_c=t3.product_code
;
```